How do I get to the "deployed Solution" for a fixed issue in SF?
According to https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAzSEAA0/hyperlink-formula-displaying-_hl_encoded_-when-referencing-another-formula-field , the issue is now "Solution Deployed"
How do we know what is the solution now or what are the required steps to ensure the issue is resolved for that specific case ? Seems the HYPERLINK issue generating a HL_ENCODED string instead of a working URL is still an issue (we tried today again).
Thanks for any hint to find that solution for W-6582821 ...
-Arnaud

And for kicks: here 's a summary of the general issue with HYPERLINK() : when creating a row level formula to recreate a field as "Account + ID" with a link to the account record, we get a HL_ENCODED string instead of a working URL.
formula = HYPERLINK("https://shfb.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/"&npe01__OppPayment__c.npe01__Opportunity__c.Account.Account_ID_18_Digit__c&"/view",npe01__OppPayment__c.npe01__Opportunity__c.Account.Name & " (" & npe01__OppPayment__c.npe01__Opportunity__c.Account.Constituent_Id__c & ")", '_self')

Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick tour. We request that comments be left for clarifying questions/responses, while additional information for the question should be made with an [edit]. Also, unfortunately, we're mostly volunteers, not actual employees, and so don't have direct access to the bug tracker salesforce.com engineers use. It would also be helpful to describe how you encountered the problem and steps you've tried to resolve it. The more information we have, the better we can help.
